# Position the brace in the decorations package in a TikZ diagram

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a trapezoid and its diagonals drawn.  The midpoints of the bases and the intersection of the diagonals are collinear.  (If anyone can give me a reference for this proposition, I would appreciate it.)  I include this line, drawn in green.  I would like to get the tip of the brace on the green line without "moving the endpoints a bit to the left and seeing that it ain't quite right and moving the endpoints a bit down."

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.markings,backgrounds,patterns}


\begin{document}

    \begin{tikzpicture}

    %Trapezoid ABCD is drawn.
    \coordinate (A) at (0,0);
    \coordinate (B) at (5.5,0);
    \coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(110:2.25)$);
    \coordinate (D) at ($(C) +(-2.5,0)$);

    \draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- cycle;
    \draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
    \draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


    %The intersection of the diagonals is labeled E.
    \path[name path=a_path_to_locate_E] (A) -- (C);
    \path[name path=another_path_to_locate_E] (B) -- (D);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_E and another_path_to_locate_E, by=E}];


    %The intersections of the line through E parallel to the bases of the trapezoid are labeled
    %F and G.
    \path[name path=a_path_to_locate_F] (A) -- (D);
    \path[name path=another_path_to_locate_F] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (E) -- ($(E) +({\n1-180}:2)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_F and another_path_to_locate_F, by=F}];
    %
    \path[name path=a_path_to_locate_G] (B) -- (C);
    \path[name path=another_path_to_locate_G] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (E) -- ($(E) +(\n1:2)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_G and another_path_to_locate_G, by=G}];

    %The line segment FG through E is drawn.
    \draw (F) -- (G);


    %The labels for the trapezoid are typeset.
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
    \node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};
    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(D) +(0,0.15)$){$D$};

    \path[name path=a_path_for_label_F] ($(A)!0.15cm!90:(D)$) -- ($(D)!0.15cm!-90:(A)$);
    \path[name path=a_path_for_labels_G] ($(B)!0.15cm!-90:(C)$) -- ($(C)!0.15cm!90:(B)$);
    \path[name path=another_path_for_label_F] (F) -- ($(F)!{-0.25cm}!(G)$);
    \path[name path=another_path_for_label_G] (G) -- ($(G)!{-0.25cm}!(F)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_for_label_F and another_path_for_label_F, by=label_for_F}];
    \node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_F){$F$};
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_for_labels_G and another_path_for_label_G, by=label_for_G}];
    \node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_G){$G$};

    \node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(E) +(0,0.15)$){$E$};



    %The lengths of the bases of the trapezoid are typeset.
    \path[name path=path_for_label_for_a] ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$) -- ($(B)!0.15cm!90:(A)$);
    \path[name path=path_for_label_for_c] ($(C)!0.15cm!-90:(D)$) -- ($(D)!0.15cm!90:(C)$);
    \draw[green,  name path=the_line_through_E_and_the_midpoints_of_the_bases] let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in
    ($($(A)!0.5!(B)$) +({\n1-180}:0.25)$) -- ($($(C)!0.5!(D)$) +(\n1:0.25)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_a and the_line_through_E_and_the_midpoints_of_the_bases, by=label_for_a}];
    \path let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_a){$a$};
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_c and the_line_through_E_and_the_midpoints_of_the_bases, by=label_for_c}];
    \path let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_c){$c$};

    %The length of FG is typeset. Its length is labeled e. As the midpoints of the bases are collinear
    %with E, the label for the length of FG is typeset on the line containing these three points.
    \draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2.5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] (F) -- (G);
    \path[name path=path_for_label_for_e] ($(F)!0.35cm!-90:(G)$) -- ($(G)!0.35cm!90:(F)$);
    \coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_e and the_line_through_E_and_the_midpoints_of_the_bases, by=label_for_e}];
    \draw let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_e){$e$};

    \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For brace you need to have TikZ library `decorations.pathreplacing` an not `decorations.markings`. With this change, your MWE works. However, I do not understand your code at all, so, on basis obtained image with your code:

[image]

I rewrote your code completely:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{angles,backgrounds,calc,
                decorations.pathreplacing,intersections,
                patterns,positioning,quotes}
    \usepackage{mathtools}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
every label/.style = {font=\footnotesize, inner sep=2pt}
                        ]
    % Coordinates with labels of trapezoid vertices
\coordinate[label=below:$A$] (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate[label=below:$B$] (B) at (5.5,0);
\coordinate[label=above:$C$] (C) at ($(B) +(110:2.25)$);
\coordinate[label=above:$D$] (D) at ($(C) +(-2.5,0)$);
     % Trapezoid ABCD is drawn.
\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C)    (B) -- (D);

    % Coordinates E, F and G with labels
\coordinate[label=above:$E$] (E) at (intersection cs:first line={(A)--(C)}, 
                                    second line={(B)--(D)});
\coordinate[label= left:$F$] (F) at (intersection cs:first line={(A)--(D)}, 
                                    second line={(E)--(E-|A)});
\coordinate[label=right:$G$] (G) at (intersection cs:first line={(B)--(C)}, 
                                    second line={(E)--(E-|B)});
    % Line F -- G 
\draw (F) -- (G);
    % Green line a -- c with labels a, e and c
\draw[green, shorten >=-2mm, shorten <=-2mm] 
    ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) node[label=below:$a$] {} --
                    coordinate[label=left:$e$] (e)
    ($(C)!0.5!(D)$) node[label=above:$c$] {};
    % brace between F and G, it is not clear if it have a node, so ???
\draw[decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2.5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror},red] 
    (F) -- node[below=5pt] {???} (G);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Is image and code what you looking for?

**Edit:** After reading your answer I figured out that main problem is how to put braces below "extreme" on green line on deterministic way.  So I change Addendum again. Now it contain one of the possible ways how to calculate  aspect ratio, which results in desired result.

**Addendum:** From your answer I figured out that you like to have asymmetric brace which with starting point on green line a -- c. For this I employ option `aspect`:

[image]

For this image I change the end of above code after line with `\draw (F) -- (G);`:

```
    % Green line a -- c with labels a and c
\draw[green, shorten >=-1pt, shorten <=-1pt] 
    ($(A)!0.5!(B)$) coordinate[label=below:$a$] (a) --
    ($(C)!0.5!(D)$) coordinate[label=above:$c$] (c) ;
    % brace parallel to line between F and E,
\draw  let \p1 = ($(c)-(a-|c)$),
            \p2 = ($(a)-(a-|c)$),
            \n1 = {veclen(\y1,\x1)},
            \n2 = {veclen(\y2,\x2)} in
    [decorate,
     decoration={brace,raise=2.5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror,
     aspect=0.5-0.075*\n2/\n1   % 0.075=(raise + amplitude)/(100 pt)
                },red,
     ]
    (F) -- node[below=6pt,xshift=-8.5pt*\n2/\n1,% 8,5pt = 2,5pt + 6pt
                font=\footnotesize] {$e$}   (G);

    \end{tikzpicture}
```

In code's comments are described, how is calculated option `aspect` and how is calculated shift of node below brace. I hope that I'm now understand your question correctly.

Comment: I apologize for not having `decorations.pathreplacing` in the preamble.  I will edit my code now so that other members will not be frustrated with it not compiling.  Using your code, the placement of `a`, `c`, and `e` are not on the green line.  Whether you understand my code, you may compile it (after you add `decorations.pathreplacing` to the preamble) and see the diagram.  It is exactly what I want except for the placement of the brace.

Comment: Nope.  The brace indicates the length of FG.  I want the center of the brace on the green line.  (I would later delete the green line.)

Comment: well, search for solution with guessing is not fruitful way. I correct addendum, see, if now is close to what you looking for. For further improvement of my answer, you need to provide a sketch, which show, what you like to obtain. obviously, we not understand each other.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly what I wanted.  (I edited my code to give the same diagram.  I am posting my code, too.)

Comment: After reading your answer I correct my addendum in answer again. See, if this (deterministic) solution work for you. At least all code is very concise and easy to read and understand.

Answer (score 0):

```
\documentclass{amsart}
\usepackage{mathtools}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,angles,positioning,intersections,quotes,decorations.pathreplacing}


\begin{document}


\begin{tikzpicture}

%Trapezoid ABCD is drawn.
\coordinate (A) at (0,0);
\coordinate (B) at (5.5,0);
\coordinate (C) at ($(B) +(110:2.25)$);
\coordinate (D) at ($(C) +(-2.5,0)$);

\draw (A) -- (B) -- (C) -- (D) -- (A) -- cycle;
\draw[dashed] (A) -- (C);
\draw[dashed] (B) -- (D);


%The intersection of the diagonals is labeled E.
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_E] (A) -- (C);
\path[name path=another_path_to_locate_E] (B) -- (D);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_E and another_path_to_locate_E, by=E}];


%The intersections of the line through E parallel to the bases of the trapezoid are labeled
%F and G.
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_F] (A) -- (D);
\path[name path=another_path_to_locate_F] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (E) -- ($(E) +({\n1-180}:2)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_F and another_path_to_locate_F, by=F}];
%
\path[name path=a_path_to_locate_G] (B) -- (C);
\path[name path=another_path_to_locate_G] let \p1=($(A)-(B)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in (E) -- ($(E) +(\n1:2)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_to_locate_G and another_path_to_locate_G, by=G}];

%The line segment FG through E is drawn.
\draw (F) -- (G);


%The labels for the trapezoid are typeset.
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(A) +(0,-0.15)$){$A$};
\node[anchor=north, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(B) +(0,-0.15)$){$B$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(C) +(0,0.15)$){$C$};
\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(D) +(0,0.15)$){$D$};

\path[name path=a_path_for_label_F] ($(A)!0.15cm!90:(D)$) -- ($(D)!0.15cm!-90:(A)$);
\path[name path=a_path_for_labels_G] ($(B)!0.15cm!-90:(C)$) -- ($(C)!0.15cm!90:(B)$);
\path[name path=another_path_for_label_F] (F) -- ($(F)!{-0.25cm}!(G)$);
\path[name path=another_path_for_label_G] (G) -- ($(G)!{-0.25cm}!(F)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_for_label_F and another_path_for_label_F, by=label_for_F}];
\node[anchor=east, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_F){$F$};
\coordinate[name intersections={of=a_path_for_labels_G and another_path_for_label_G, by=label_for_G}];
\node[anchor=west, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_G){$G$};

\node[anchor=south, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at ($(E) +(0,0.15)$){$E$};



%The lengths of the bases of the trapezoid are typeset. The midpoints of the bases are collinear
%with E.  For convenience, the line through the midpoints of the bases and E is called
%"the_middle_line." 
\path[name path=path_for_label_for_a] ($(A)!0.15cm!-90:(B)$) -- ($(B)!0.15cm!90:(A)$);
\path[name path=path_for_label_for_c] ($(C)!0.15cm!-90:(D)$) -- ($(D)!0.15cm!90:(C)$);
\draw[green,  name path=the_middle_line] let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in
($($(A)!0.5!(B)$) +({\n1-180}:0.25)$) -- ($($(C)!0.5!(D)$) +(\n1:0.25)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_a and the_middle_line, by=label_for_a}];
\path let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_a){$a$};
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_c and the_middle_line, by=label_for_c}];
\path let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor={\n1-180}, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_c){$c$};

%The length of FG is typeset. Its length is labeled e. As the midpoints of the bases are collinear
%with E, the label for the length of FG is typeset on the line containing these three points.
%A brace is typeset under FG. To be sure that the center of the brace is on the_middle_line, a line
%0.25cm under FG is drawn.  For convenience, this line is called "the_line_under_FG."  The endpoints
%of the brace is half the length of FG from the intersection of the_middle_line and the_line_under_FG.
%Since the options raise=2.5pt and amplitude=5pt are used, and since FG is a horizontal line, to
%center the tip of the brace on the_middle_line, both endpoints are raised 7.5pt.
\path[name path=the_line_under_FG] ($(F)!0.25cm!-90:(G)$) -- ($(G)!0.25cm!90:(F)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=the_middle_line and the_line_under_FG, by=center_for_brace}];
\draw[green,  decorate,decoration={brace,raise=2.5pt,amplitude=5pt,mirror}] let \p1=(F), \p2=(G), \n1={veclen((\x2-\x1), (\y2-\y1))} in
($(center_for_brace) +({-1*(0.5*\n1)},0) +(0,7.5pt)$) -- ($(center_for_brace) +({0.5*\n1},0) +(0,7.5pt)$);
%
\path[name path=path_for_label_for_e] ($(F)!0.35cm!-90:(G)$) -- ($(G)!0.35cm!90:(F)$);
\coordinate[name intersections={of=path_for_label_for_e and the_middle_line, by=label_for_e}];
\draw let \p1=($($(A)!0.5!(B)$)-($(C)!0.5!(D)$)$), \n1={atan(\y1/\x1)} in node[anchor=\n1, inner sep=0, font=\footnotesize] at (label_for_e){$e$};

\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```